# How to back up .NEF files to cloud in a simple and affordable way?

Tags: backup, raw

I'm looking for a way to easily and affordably make backups of my .NEF files. Ideally the solution should be:

- As simple and easy to use as Dropbox (or even be automatic plugin in Aperture or action in when plugging in a SD card to reader)
- As low-cost as google paid storage
- Work on Mac and Windows

Are there any?

Comment: Here might be some clues, although usability is not covered and question is only about Mac: [What options are there for good, cheap online backup of data?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8595/what-options-are-there-for-good-cheap-online-backup-of-data)

Answer (score 2):

There are several services available (see below, copied from my answer to the linked question).

Regarding usability: These services generally allow you to configure a specific collection of directories which are then scanned for changes. Whenever a change occurs the new files or amendments are uploaded, so there is no manual effort involved. The online utilities for retrieving files can vary, so I would suggest looking at the demo pages for these services.

The market for online cloud backup is competitive but I'm not sure if these are as cheap as [Google paid storage.](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/pricingandterms.html)

- [Mozy](http://mozy.com)
- [Carbonite](http://www.carbonite.com/)
- [BackBlaze](http://www.backblaze.com)
- [CrashPlan](http://crashplan.com)
- [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com)
- [SugarSync](http://www.sugarsync.com)

Comment: I had a great experience with CrashPlan so far.  I use their software to backup to an external drive (free) and also to backup to the Cloud (paid).  At less then $3/month with the 4 year plan, it's a steal for unlimited Cloud storage (currently I have 200GB).  If you don't want to pay for Cloud storage, you can do peer-to-peer backups for free.  I also like the iOS app, you can download photos and files to your iPad.  I once forgot to copy a document to my laptop, so I just downloaded it to my iPhone and emailed me back at work.

Comment: +1 on Crashplan. I will add a CRITICAL feature that is NOT in the others: backup of disconnected drives. Crashplan saves data from drives not connected. Others will delete data from drives they have not seen for 30 days. I have archive disks where this would be tragic, as they are older images I don't have online all the time, but they are on hard drives that have not been plugged into my Mac in months.