# Best options to store photos

Tags: storage

I am looking for a cloud based storage to store my images. I would require a decent uploader and browsing interface. It would be great if I can use that storage APIs to write my own browsing software.

Answer (score 2):

Storage is easy, and there are thousands of options. What I believe is critical is what *else* you need beyond storage.

What kind of files..JPEG, JPEG+RAW, RAW only.

What kind of viewing... confirm image files are stored, view photos, sort/view/share photos.

What other types of files...psd, tiff, dng, library backup.

1. Storage only: Amazon S3, Crashplan, Mozy, Backblaze. These solutions are backup/storage services, where you can view the files online, but not photos. In otherwords, you can confirm a list of image files uploaded, but not view the images themselves. Amazon S3 has APIs, all others use their own client interfaces. These have the benefit of being able to store not only images, but also any other file type, including LR or Aperture library files, psd, tiff, dng files.
2. Storage and viewing. Again, thousands of solutions.  Some like Dropbox, provide real-time access and replication, others, like Smugmug, store your JPEG files for sharing and viewing, and via integrated Amazon S3, can also store your associated RAW files.
3. Viewing and sharing. Thousands of options again. Services such as Flickr, Picasa, 500px, focus on sharing of JPEGs only, though of course are a sort of 'backup', since these files live in the 'cloud'. Typically, bulk download can be much more troublesome than solutions in #2 above.

Comment: This is a good, helpful answer. Would you consider moving it to the other question this is a duplicate of?

Comment: Another to add to the list is Secure Capsule, it's an archiving service backed by AWS S3 and glacier, you get a heap of free storage, the large plans are really affordable and we offer immediate access to thumbnails and previews.  The raw files can be restored after about 4 hours (they come off glacier) which keeps the cost really low.  Disclaimer I am the founder of Secure Capsule.

Comment: Thanks @mattdm I added it to the duplicate question. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8595/what-options-are-there-for-good-cheap-online-backup-of-photos/37704#37704

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just off the top of my head to look at Dropbox.  The "Image Uploader" so to speak is as easy as dragging and dropping files in Explorer (or Finder if you're mac-oriented).

It has a [fairly] decent picture browser already for files you place in the Photos folder when you access it via. the web.

And it has a public API so you can write your own apps to upload/download/view/etc images and files you put there.

You get - I think - 2Gb free storage with the option to purchase more.

It's also completely cross platform not only for desktop OS's, but also has apps for iPhone/iPad/Blackberry/Android/Kindle Fire etc....